# Trying to get wifi working in Lubuntu 14.04 on Inspiron B120

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, lubuntu, broadcom

I'm having a hell of a time getting wifi working on this old laptop.  Google turns up lots of people having similar problems, but all the answers seem to be from 2010 - 2011 and aren't working for me.

This laptop has:
Network controller      : Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g

It's supposedly using the Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source, but the only network interfaces I have are lo and eth0.

Googling suggests that there's a conflict with ssb, which is used by b44, but any attempts to rmmod that result in killing eth0 and no wifi.  One step keeps getting me a segmentation fault.  I think that step was modprobe wl...

Anyway, I'm working off 3 and 4 year old answers, and they just aren't working.  Help!

Comment: what's the command `lspci -v` say about the "driver in use" for your network controller?

Answer (score 0):

To get wlan0 up try:

```
sudo modprobe b44
```

and then type

```
sudo iwconfig
```

to see if wlan0 is listed in the output

You may need to use

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

to get it going after it is recognized.